# How to solve problems involving overlapping pairs and which data structure to use

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization, data-structures

There is a railway station whose traffic information we have, its like (arrival,departure) time pairs of trains visiting the station. Something like this T{ [1,5],[2,4],[5,9],[3,10] }. Then how to find minimum number of platforms needed to manage this traffic.

Comment: Is this homework? Then you should tag it as such.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find out the maximum overlap, right? This will give you the minimum number of platforms. Just initialize an array with `max(times)` elements equal to 0, and add then iterate through each `(arrival, departure)` interval, adding 1 to each element of the array that is in the interval.

Then the maximum value of any element of the array is the minimum number of platforms you'll need. This works with integer-valued intervals. The array might not be the quickest method, though. I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution in time O(n log n), where n is the number of time pairs given.
You have to answer the question: How many trains are standing in the station at the same time?
To do that, we first "normalize" the time values: Identify all time segments something interesting can happen in. To do so, sort all arrival and departure times given and eliminate duplicates.

In your example with T = {[1,5], [2,4], [5,9], [3,10]}, this results in an array
A with time points [1,2,3,4,5,9,10] and size m = 7.

Now we translate the arrival and departure time of each pair into the time segments the train is occupying the station, i. e. we find the index of the time values in the array A (via binary search). E. g. for [3, 10], we get indices 2 and 6, counting from zero.

That was it for the easy part. Sorting and matching time values with indices run in O(n log n) each. Now we have to count for each index, how many trains are standing in the station at that time. To do that efficiently, we use a segment tree.

This site gives an introduction on how to use segment trees:
http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor#Segment_Trees

In the following, you'll find a implementation in C++. I hope you can adapt it to your needs. If any questions remain open, do not hesitate to ask.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

/** Given a number n and n pairs of arrival and departure times of trains,
*  this program calculates the number of platforms needed in time O(n log n)
*  If a train arrives exactly when another one leaves the station, you need
*  two platforms. */

int main () {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector< pair<int,int> > T(n);
    vector< int           > A(2*n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int arrival, departure;
        cin >> arrival >> departure;
        A[2*i]   = arrival;
        A[2*i+1] = departure;
        T[i] = pair<int,int>(arrival, departure);
    }
    sort(A.begin(), A.end());
    int m = unique(A.begin(), A.end()) - A.begin();

    // for easy indexing, we need m to be a potency of 2
    int pot2m = 1; while (pot2m < m) pot2m *= 2;

    // Elements pot2m ... pot2m + m represent the bottom layer of the segment tree
    vector< int > segtree(2*pot2m+1, 0);

    // Now let's add everything up
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int arrival   = find(A.begin(), A.end(), T[i].first)  - A.begin();
        int departure = find(A.begin(), A.end(), T[i].second) - A.begin();
        // Now increment
        int a = arrival + pot2m;
        int b = departure + pot2m + 1;
        while (a < b) {
            if (a % 2 == 1) ++segtree[a];
            if (b % 2 == 1) ++segtree[b-1];
            a = (a+1) / 2;
            b = b / 2;
        }
    }

    // Find the maximum value in the cells
    int a = pot2m;
    int b = pot2m + m;
    while (a < b) {
        int i, j;
        for (i = a/2, j = a; j < b-1; ++i, j+=2) {
            segtree[i] += max(segtree[j], segtree[j+1]);
        }
        if (j == b-1) segtree[i] += segtree[j]; // To handle odd borders
        a /= 2;
        b /= 2;
    }
    cout << "You need " << segtree[1] << " platforms." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will go with your subject line question "How to solve these kind of problems and which data structure is better to handle?"

You have given an example for the above. This kind of problems are known as Optimization Problems (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_problem).

Choice of data structure will be based upon space/time trade off's. So for instance one can solve the above problem by using a simple array or a hash table or maybe a graph. What is really important is sometimes it might take exponential running time in solving such problems which might make them NP-Complete/Hard. Say considering your example you have n platforms and m trains (where n & m are very large) then there is a possibility of combinatorial explosion.

Also if it results in exponential time and say is an NP-Complete/Hard problem then there are several heuristic algorithms (For an example a Travelling Salesman Problem can be solved using Ant Colony Optimization) too for solving it, maybe not the most optimal one.

Algorithms are more important here in this context than Data Structures.

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of structures like this: (Time, IsArrival), where IsArrival = +1 for arrival or -1 for departure

Sort it by time key (take into account a case of equal times)

Initialize PlatformsNeeded = 0

Walk through sorted array, add IsArrival to PlatformsNeeded, remember max value